# Dynamically Changing an Injected CSS Class ...Good? ...Bad?

Tags: javascript, css

**Dynamically Changing an Injected CSS Class ...Good?  ...Bad?**

I found a 'need' to modify a CSS Class that I inject into the header vis javascript.  Because I build the class dynamically and inject it into the header, I found it easy to modify the Class's text and put it back into the CSS Class definition whereby changing it.

By inject, I mean:
    `var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = ".classname { ...css text... }";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);`

and by modifying the Class, I mean simply changing the text:
    `{ ...css text... }`

and putting it back:
    `style.innerHTML = ".classname { ...new css text... }";`

I really have not seen this done before and am asking if there is a reason that this is not done more often?  ...that is, "is this a bad practice?"  and perhaps  "are there browser/device combinations where this may not work?"

Thank you.

Comment: rather than changing the css text that way, you should add a second class in the css, and then change the class of the DOM element.

Comment: Why would you do this to change text? Since you already are using javascript instead of updating css, you can update the dom directly?

Comment: Quick! I was still editing to fix the code blocks.  Anyway, other ways exist, yes.  This is a large, vendor prefixed css transitions class. Often the time changes proportionally to the state of the view.  So I simply replace the time from, say, `0.5s` to `var+'s'` and it worked fine.  So this precipitated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad practice.  A CSS class should have a single definition.  Modifying the class conditionally makes your code hard to follow and hard to maintain.

The correct way would to be create a separate CSS class for each condition, or modify the DOM directly using Javascript.

Comment: Well, as I expected, not so good.  But what about the second part of the question? ..."will this technique work across all/most browsers?" ...or perhaps, it is known to be problematic.

Comment: It will work across browsers with the same caveat as any other CSS, which is you may have to account for differences in browsers and versions in your CSS.  There is nothing about any browser version that I know of that will prevent you from modifying the CSS class dynamically.